# Safe to Lubricate Bar Valve in Shower Mixer Tap?

Tags: faucet, valve, bathroom-fixtures, lubrication

In my bath/shower I've had a new mixer tap fitted that has a bar valve (when the tap is running you lift the valve to make the water come out of the shower head. When you turn the tap off, the valve falls back down so that the water will come out of the tap again.)

My valve is a sticky and sometimes it's very hard to lift it. When I do lift it, it won't fall back down on its own and can be difficult to push down.

Is it safe to lubricate it?

Here's a photo of the tap and one with the valve without the screw-on cap:
[image: tap]
[image: valve]

Comment: Yes it is safe but with dubious success because water runs over the gate and mechanism every time you use it and will wash the lube away. Is it the kind where the diverter gate is part of the tub spout?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it thanks for the reply. I have added some photos of the tap. Do you have any alternative suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like a rubber gasket/washer or o-ring on the gate/disc/wedge has become misaligned or is damaged. See the flat spots on the valve body in your photo? This indicates to me that the valve can be disassembled using an adjustable wrench or end wrench/spanner; so you can check the valve disc sealing surface to ascertain the root cause and then fix it.